# SQl no PostgreSQL: Não Repetir Valores de uma campo da Table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, select

Tenho um select que exibe os nomes, data e valores pagos por clientes. 
Devo fazer exibir uma lista sem repetir os nomes.

```
SELECT  
    c.name,
    p.created_at,
    p.amount_paid
FROM 
    payments as p, 
    clients as c
WHERE 
  p.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND p.created_at > CURRENT_DATE -199
```

[image: post]

Comment: se não vai repetir os nomes, terá que agrupar data e valor, normalmente. Você pode usar a primeira ou última data, média ou soma dos valores. O que precisa ?

Comment: a ideia é somar os pagamentos de cada cliente

Comment: como os pagamentos forma feitos no dia anterior, nao precisa agrupar por data

Comment: mas se tem várias datas, você precisa colocar em uma função de agregação, ou agrupar pela data

Comment: não precisa. o campo data é unico: dia anterior!

Comment: o objetivo é não repetir o nome do cliente e somar todos so pagamentos feito por ele no dia anteiror

Comment: nesse caso, a data entra no agrupamento. veja a resposta

Comment: Para que serve a tabela `receipt_status` ? Como a tabela `clients` está se relacionando com as demais ? E o propósito da tabela `receipts` ?? Você quer o somatório de `amount_paid` agrupado pela data de criação `created_at`  ?

Comment: editei o codigo. Mas já pubilcaram a resposta para meu problema!

Comment: Que tal postar a estrutura original das tabelas ?

Comment: Estou em duvida quanto a selecionar todos os campos das tabelas!!

Comment: como posso selecionar outros campos das tabelas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tabelas `receipt_status` e `receipts` não são necessárias nessa *query*, elas não se relacionam com nenhuma outra tabela e nenhum de seus campos são recuperados!

Não consegui ver como calcular os "valores pagos pagos pelos clientes" se a tabela `client` não se relaciona de nenhuma forma com as demais tabelas!

Sugiro que você reveja a lógica da sua *query*, apesar de funcionar, certamente não está recuperando a informação de forma correta.

A solução proposta seria *algo como*:

```
SELECT  
    c.name,
    p.created_at,
    SUM(p.amount_paid) AS total_amount_paid
FROM 
    payments AS p 
JOIN
    payment_status AS ps ON ( ps.id = p.payment_status_id ) 
CROSS JOIN
    clients AS c
WHERE 
    p.created_at BETWEEN current_date - '199 days'::interval AND current_date
GROUP BY
    c.name,
    p.created_at;
```